# Can a cell have both data validation and vlookup at the same time?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have 2 cells. One is a product description and one is a product number. The way it exists now, the product description is data validated and the product number is a lookup by description.

What I want to happen is to be able to lookup based on product number or product description so that basically if I select the product number from a drop down list the product description is lookup and if I select the product description from a drop down list the product number is lookup.

Is this possible or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: It is feasible. You need to use change event. By control of event `Target` parameter you are able to either search description or product number.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering an old question as no one else did precisely...** Hope this helps others as well. Also, refer to the comments in the code.

This cannot be done with Excel Formula & Validation as it would create **circular reference** [not that you cannot change the count of circular iteration, but still...]

It is much simpler in VBA... Here is the code for any one who wants to use it..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const sNumRng As String = "$A$1"
    Const sDescRng As String = "$B$1"
    '# both sListRngNum & sListRngDesc must be of the same size
    Const sListRngNum As String = "$K$1:$K$4"
    Const sListRngDesc As String = "$L$1:$L$4"

    '# EnableEvnent should be disabled first
    '# because the code will trigger it again
    '# by changing the next cell value
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = sNumRng Then
       Range(sDescRng).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(sListRngDesc), _
       WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Value, Range(sListRngNum), 0))
    ElseIf Target.Address = sDescRng Then
       Range(sNumRng).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range(sListRngNum), _
       WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Value, Range(sListRngDesc), 0))
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Paste this code in the *Sheet module* of the sheet where you want to implement this.
Change the range address according to your need. Also, this could have been done by dynamic array, collections etc..etc.. but this is much simple :)